# How to check if time is between two time intervals

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pendulum

I'm currently trying to figure out how I can make a duration between 1 AM to 7 AM (01:00-07:00) using [Pendulum](https://pendulum.eustace.io/docs/) - I have been trying to read the documentation and the closests thing I could find was using `duration` however I was not able to see how I can check if the time is between 01:00 to 07:00.

I wonder if it is possible to use pendulum to check if the time is between the interval?

Expect:

Print out "The time is between 01:00 to 07:00" and if its not then print "The time is NOT between 01:00 to 07:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you're looking to determine if a given time is between 01:00 and 07:00.  To be honest, you could getaway with just using `datetime` rather than installing a new package.  With `datetime`, I would just do:

```
import datetime
curr_time = datetime.datetime.now()  # replace this line with whatever time or how you get your time
if curr_time.hour >= 1 and curr_time.hour < 7:
    print("The time is between 01:00 to 07:00")
else:
    print("The time is NOT between 01:00 and 07:00")
```

Since `pendulum` inherits from `datetime` anyway, this should be compatible if you *really* want to use `pendulum`.  You'll just need to change some syntax.

Comment: That was so easy… My thoughts overcomplicated it and it is actually easy as your example! Thanks!